# Free memory used by a std::string

Tags: c++, linux, stdstring

I have a `struct` that looks like this:

```
struct queue_item_t {
    int id;
    int size;
    std::string content;
};
```

I have a `std::vector< queue_item_t >` which is populated with many of these from a database query.

When each item is processed, a file is read from disk and its contents put into the `content` string member. The item is processed (`content` is parsed) and I execute `.clear()` on the string so as not to eat up all my memory.

However, this doesn't seem to free the memory. I have hundreds of thousands of items being processed and eventually, the memory usage will rise beyond what's available and the application is killed by Linux with "Out-Of-Memory" as reason.

How do I free the memory used by these strings?

Comment: do you need `content` as a member of the struct ? From your explanation, it sounds like it's only used very briefly, so a temporary might be better suited for the task. Additionally, why not use a `std::queue` rather than a `std::vector` ?

Comment: The fact that your struct is called `queue_item_t` suggests that the vector of them represents some kind of queue. If that's the case, why don't you remove the elements from the queue once they're processed? I ask because it may be that the proper fix to your problem lies elsewhere. Destroying them (and their `content` string) is a pretty sure way to release their resources! Then you just have to deal with the fact that removing from the start of a vector isn't efficient -- so use `deque` instead, or if the order they're processed doesn't matter then process in reverse order.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker the part I'm doing now is just the second part of the whole process; under normal operation, the data is never read from files but retrieved from the Internet and the data put directly in the `content` string of each item that has been downloaded. But you are right, that under different circumstances, a temporary variable would be better.

Comment: If for each item in the queue, you retrieve the content, process the content, and then discard it, then the exact method of retrieving and processing doesn't matter. The content (or even the item) is still discarded as soon as it's processed, so it seems it doesn't need to be stored in the queue - it can just be passed around as function parameters or similar. If I'm missing something, a representative code sample would probably be useful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

std::string and std::vector do not change container capacity (=> do not release container memory) in clear(). The below trick with temporary object should be used whenever compaction is required (normally it is not required).

```
my_queue_item.content.clear(); // clear
std::string(my_queue_item.content).swap(my_queue_item.content); // compact
```

above code can be made simpler when cleanup+compaction are requried:

```
std::string().swap(my_queue_item.content);
```

Some string implementations are copy-on-write. Such string, when referred from more than one place, would re-allocate memory on write.

Comment: -1 I don't believe your first sentence is accurate. How do you know no memory is released in `clear`? It probably is in fact. Internally, a string has a `char*`. When you assign a different value to a string, the old one is replaced. Without a memory release, std::string would leak memory, which it doesn't.

Comment: And C++11 adds a `shrink_to_fit` member function, which is a non-binding request to the implementation to do something sensible.

Comment: @Luchian: `clear` is guaranteed not to reduce the `capacity` of the string, so it pretty much cannot free memory.

Comment: @SteveJessop so it just replaces all characters with 0?

Comment: @Luchian Grigore - copy-on-write feature of the std::basic_string, which you are most probably referring to is only activated in multithreaded environment, clear() is setting size to 0 and the first byte of the storage to '\0'

Comment: What's wrong with [`std::string().swap(my_queue_item.content);`? (see ideone)](http://ideone.com/IYorg#view_edit_box)

Comment: @Luchian: actually I may have made a mistake. *vectors* talk a lot about when reallocation occurs and more importantly when it doesn't, and `clear()` doesn't. But I can't find equivalent text for strings, so it might be deliberately left more open what their capacity represents. Certainly `string::clear` is not guaranteed to reduce the capacity. Assuming it doesn't, it won't replace all the characters with anything, in practice it will set the first character to 0, and set either an internal size field to 0, or an internal end pointer equal to the start of the string.

Comment: ... basically, it would be inefficient if *every* call to `erase` causes a reallocation. Maybe an implementation is permitted to reallocate when a call to `erase` removes enough data that it thinks it's worthwhile, maybe it isn't, I'm not sure. If it is, then `clear` is certainly the most inviting case to treat specially, since it's defined to do `erase(begin(), end())`, so by definition it erases everything. But without a guarantee, you're better off explicitly shrinking.

Comment: @sehe - nothing is wrong with it(+1), the original variant of my answer was exactly it, I have just decided to generalize it afterwards

Comment: This seemed to solve my memory issue. I don't have a -particular- issue with this being inefficient for now. Thanks!

Comment: @steve Jessop: "clear is guaranteed not to reduce the capacity..": Where is this documented? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/clear/ does not tell anything about it

Comment: @stefan: see my later comment, addressed to Luchian. Actually I'm not sure what's allowed to change the capacity of a `string`, I was thinking of `vector` and assuming the same would apply. The relevant part of my claim wan't that `clear` is guaranteed not to release memory (which may be false), but that it's not guaranteed to release memory (which I still claim).

Comment: @stefanbachert C++11 FDIS: `21.4.4/15` says `clear();` is equal to `erase(begin(), end());`, which in turn is defined in `21.4.6.5/9`, which literally says: `removes the characters in the range [first,last)`. This only modifies the character array and the position of `end()`, not the memory allocated already.

Answer (score 1):

`clear` won't free **all** the memory of the string (probably just the buffer). It will just set the string to an empty one.

If you *can* call `clear` on the string, why not reuse it instead? So, instead of creating a new `queue_item_t`, simply replace its string member with the new value.

Answer (score 1):

To free memory you can do just:

```
my_queue_item.content = "";
my_queue_item.content.shrink_to_fit();
```

The method `shrink_to_fit()` will nicely free memory and allocate small enough space for new value of `my_queue_item.content` (15 bytes for this case).

Comment: Unfortunately shrink_to_fit() is not binding so might well just be ignored, which does make it seem a rather pointless function when it could have been a very useful one.

Answer (score 0):

`clear` may not release the memory. It will logically set the string to an empty string, but may not affect the memory already allocated.

If you are reading more data into the same `queue_item_t`, it should replace the previous string content.

Are you sure you are not leaking the `queue_item_t` themselves?